# Rigorous definition of geometric similarity?

Tags: geometry

On wikipedia it says : " Two geometrical objects are called similar if one can be obtained from the other by uniformly scaling (enlarging or reducing), possibly with additional translation, rotation and reflection"

What is the rigorous definition of uniform scaling ?

Comment: Read a bit further: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry)#Similarity_in_Euclidean_space

Comment: See also this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_(geometry) and this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation